# Yaml Pipeline - Maintanence task to Keep only N, N-1 & N-2 image version

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml, podman

I have Azure devops infra to build and deploy the image. We are deploying the image to Podman.
My podman image format is something like imageV1.2.3, its a latest image deployed to podman and associated with the container and there are few more images for same application as below.

```
imageV1.2.3 - associated with container - N version
imageV1.2.2 - N-1
imageV1.2.1 - N-2
imageV1.2.8
imageV1.0.0
```

Part of my yaml pipeline I need to perform a maintanence task to do cleanup of older images except N, N-1 & N-2 everytime.

Could you please advice on this?

Comment: where are the podman v1.x.x images stored?

Comment: its on a Linux server used for both Build agent as well as dev infra deployment.